# Set initial value in datepicker with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to set an initial value in my jquery ui datepicker. I've tried several different ways, but nothing seems to display the date, it's empty.

```
var idag = new Date();
$("#txtFrom").datepicker("setDate", idag - 2);
$("#txtTom").datepicker("setDate", idag);
$("#txtFrom").datepicker("refresh");
$("#txtTom").datepicker("refresh");
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you need to call the `refresh` method. Are you able to provide a wider scope as to how you're using this? When are you attempting to set the date?

Comment: @ Andreas: I think I have followed it exactly, but no results. That's why I ask.

Comment: @Richard: the refresh was just a way of trying to get the text out.

Comment: @kaze I strongly advise against using Swedish (or any other non-English language for that matter) in your code. Since pretty much everything that isn't written by you will be in English you're going to be mixing languages, and you are making it difficult for non-Swedish speakers to maintain your code. I don't see the downside to using English because good luck finding a Swedish programmer who doesn't speak English :) `</rant>`

Answer (score 102, accepted):

This simple [example](http://jsfiddle.net/dittodhole/epHNZ/) works for me...

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

**JavaScript**

```
var $datepicker = $('#datepicker');
$datepicker.datepicker();
$datepicker.datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

I was able to create this by simply looking [@ the manual](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#methods) and reading the explanation of [`setDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate):

> .datepicker( "setDate" , date )
>   Sets the current date for the datepicker. The new date may be a Date
>   object or a string in the current date format (e.g. '01/26/2009'), a
>   number of days from today (e.g. +7) or a string of values and periods
>   ('y' for years, 'm' for months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for days, e.g. '+1m
>   +7d'), or null to clear the selected date.

Comment: You'r right. My mistake was that I thought that I could do it at the same time as the initialization of the picker, ie, that only $("#txtTom").datepicker("setDate", idag) was enough, not needed the ("#txtTom").datepicker() first.

Comment: actually u can do it on the focus event of the datepicker, here's what I do:

$(document).on('focus', ".datepicker", function () {
            $(this).datepicker();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date($(this).val())); //set value
        });

I do this because I add datepickers dynamically so it will modify any input with datepicker class to an actual datepicker from the moment u select it

Comment: This will trigger the 'changeDate' event which might not be what you want on every page load.

Comment: Be sure you set the type property to "text" and not "date".  datepicker('setDate', date) will not work with a type of "date".

Answer (score 20):

You can set the value in the HTML and then init datepicker to start/highlight the actual date

```
<input name="datefrom" type="text" class="datepicker" value="20-1-2011">
<input name="dateto" type="text" class="datepicker" value="01-01-2012">
<input name="dateto2" type="text" class="datepicker" >


$(".datepicker").each(function() {    
    $(this).datepicker('setDate', $(this).val());
});
```

The above even works with danish date formats

http://jsfiddle.net/DDsBP/2/

Comment: $("".datepicker"").each(function() {    
 var dateValue = $(this).attr(""value"");
 if (dateValue != """"){   
  $(this).datepicker(""setDate"", dateValue);
 }
    });

Answer (score 10):

From [jQuery](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/):

> Set the date to highlight on first opening if the field is blank. Specify either an actual date via a Date object or as a string in the current dateFormat, or a number of days from today (e.g. +7) or a string of values and periods ('y' for years, 'm' for months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for days, e.g. '+1m +7d'), or null for today.

Code examples

Initialize a datepicker with the defaultDate option specified.

```
$(".selector").datepicker({ defaultDate: +7 });
```

Get or set the defaultDate option, after init.

```
//getter
var defaultDate = $(".selector").datepicker("option", "defaultDate");
//setter
$(".selector").datepicker("option", "defaultDate", +7);
```

After the datepicker is intialized you should also be able to set the date with:

```
$(/*selector*/).datepicker("setDate" , date)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Use this code it will help you.**

```
<script>
InitializeDate();
</script>




<input type="text" id="txtFromDate" class="datepicker calendar-icon" placeholder="From Date" style="width: 100px; margin-right: 10px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 7px;">
        <input type="text" id="txtToDate" class="datepicker calendar-icon" placeholder="To Date" style="width: 100px; margin-right: 10px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 7px;">


function InitializeDate() {
    var date = new Date();
    var dd = date.getDate();             
    var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var yyyy = date.getFullYear();

    var ToDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
    var FromDate = mm + '/01/' + yyyy;
    $('#txtToDate').datepicker('setDate', ToDate);
    $('#txtFromDate').datepicker('setDate', FromDate);
}
```

Comment: Please, add some intuition when posting code snippets.

Answer (score 2):

Use `setDate`

```
.datepicker( "setDate" , date )
```

> Sets the current date for the datepicker. The new date may be a Date object or a string in the current date format (e.g. '01/26/2009'), a number of days from today (e.g. +7) or a string of values and periods ('y' for years, 'm' for months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for days, e.g. '+1m +7d'), or null to clear the selected date.

Comment: -, nope ... 'Set the date to highlight on first opening if the field is blank.' @ http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate - example http://jsfiddle.net/dittodhole/epHNZ/2/

Comment: @jb10210 it is not the initial date!!! it's just "date to highlight on first opening" ... just follow my example!

Comment: @Pranav just removed my downvote - thanks pal for voting me up!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure if I understood your question, but it seems that you're trying to set value for an input type Date.

If you want to set a value for an **input type** '*Date*', then it has to be formatted as "**yyyy-MM-dd**" (Note: capital MM for Month, lower case mm for minutes). Otherwise, it will clear the value and leave the datepicker empty.

Let's say you have a button called "**DateChanger**" and you want to set your datepicker to "*22 Dec 2012*" when you click it.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#DateChanger').click(function() {
             $('#dtFrom').val("2012-12-22");
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="date" id="dtFrom" name="dtFrom" />
<button id="DateChanger">Click</button>
```

Remember to include JQuery reference.

Comment: The user asked for jQuery `datepicker` plugin.

Answer (score -1):

Use it after initialization code to get current date (in datepicker format):

```
$(".ui-datepicker-today").trigger("click");
```