# How to Show current Date into datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `datepicker` which I want to show the current date whenever the page loads but when I am doing it with simple input field it is working but the `datepicker` input field not taking the values

```js
$('#deliveryDate').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
});


var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var month = new Array();
month[0] = "01";
month[1] = "02";
month[2] = "03";
month[3] = "04";
month[4] = "05";
month[5] = "06";
month[6] = "07";
month[7] = "08";
month[8] = "09";
month[9] = "10";
month[10] = "11";
month[11] = "12"; //January is 0!
var mm = month[today.getMonth()];
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

console.log(today)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<label for="deliveryDate" id="commonHeader"> Delivery Date:</label>
<input type="text" id="deliveryDate" name="deliveryDate" width="176" />
```

Now I am getting todays date in variable `today` now I want to store that value in datepicker input field when the page loads.

Comment: What you mean exactly by _but the datepicker input field not taking the values_??

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki suppose i have calculated todays date and stored it in a variable now i want to populate that value inside the input field of date picker

Comment: @manishthakur did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915990/set-todays-date-as-default-date-in-jquery-ui-datepicker

Comment: Why you can't simply use `.val()`?

Comment: I pick the date using the calendar, and I see it displayed in the input field. What's the problem?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki  please chek the edit i have used `.val` but not working

Comment: Check my updated answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.val()` :

**Set value on page load :**

```js
$(function() {

  $('#deliveryDate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
  });

  var today = new Date();
  var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var month = new Array();

  month[0] = "01";
  month[1] = "02";
  month[2] = "03";
  month[3] = "04";
  month[4] = "05";
  month[5] = "06";
  month[6] = "07";
  month[7] = "08";
  month[8] = "09";
  month[9] = "10";
  month[10] = "11";
  month[11] = "12"; //January is 0!
  var mm = month[today.getMonth()];
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

  $('#deliveryDate').val(today);
  console.log(today);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<button id="btn">Set DATE</button>
<br>
<br>
<label for="deliveryDate" id="commonHeader"> Delivery Date:</label>
<input type="text" id="deliveryDate" name="deliveryDate" width="176" />
```

**Set value on click :**

```js
$(function() {

$('#deliveryDate').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var month = new Array();

  month[0] = "01";
  month[1] = "02";
  month[2] = "03";
  month[3] = "04";
  month[4] = "05";
  month[5] = "06";
  month[6] = "07";
  month[7] = "08";
  month[8] = "09";
  month[9] = "10";
  month[10] = "11";
  month[11] = "12"; //January is 0!
  var mm = month[today.getMonth()];
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

  $('#deliveryDate').val(today);
  console.log(today);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<button id="btn">Set DATE</button>
<br>
<br>
<label for="deliveryDate" id="commonHeader"> Delivery Date:</label>
<input type="text" id="deliveryDate" name="deliveryDate" width="176" />
```

Comment: i was trying the same don't know why it was not working, but now it worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `defaultDate` property when setting up the datepicker.

```
$('#deliveryDate').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  defaultDate: '01/01/1970'
});
```

you could use a date object there as well, or 0 for today.

for today:

```
$('#deliveryDate').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  defaultDate: 0
});

* Api Reference Link:  http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate
```

Comment: but how can i give it a dynamic date?

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic date?

Comment: you could use 0 for today, or +7 for next week, etc.

Comment: possible duplication with @https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921944/set-initial-value-in-datepicker-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var todayDate = (function(){ 
      var d = new Date();
      var day = d.getDate();
      day =  day > 9 ? day : '0' + day ;
      var month = (d.getMonth() + 1);
      month = month > 9 ? month : '0' + month;
      var _value =  day + '/' + month  + '/' + d.getFullYear(); 
      return _value; 
    })();
    $('#deliveryDate').datepicker({
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
      value: todayDate
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<label for="deliveryDate" id="commonHeader"> Delivery Date:</label>
<input type="text" id="deliveryDate" name="deliveryDate" width="176" />
```